# how to open a kendo UI modal window and pass it some help text to display, using angular

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, modal-dialog

I am looking for a simple equivalent to a `MsgBox.Show( message text)` when using kendo UI in angular, without using BootstrapUI since I'm using kendo UI.

I've read http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/13-06-24/announcing-angular-kendo-ui

but it has the modal window defined in markup.

Is there a counterpart to this jQuery version that dynamically creates the DIV and stuffs some markup into the `html` property?

```
     $(".helpimg").on("click", function (e) {

      $(document.createElement('div'))
        .attr({ title: 'Help', 'class': 'help' })
        .html(help[e.target.id])
        .dialog({
            buttons: { OK: function () { $(this).dialog('close'); } },
            close: function () { $(this).remove(); },
            draggable: true,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            width: '50%',
            height: 'auto'
        });

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically create kendo window objects by applying the `kendoWindow()` function on a dynamically created div to your document. Try this dojo and let me know if this is what you were looking for :

http://dojo.telerik.com/esaWi/2